# How to tell when an activity is shown

Tags: android, android-activity, focus

I have an app that contains a sequence of listviews, and those lists are populated with data retrieve from a webservice.  I want to refresh this data when the user presses back to go to the previous list.

I have currently tried overriding the `onWindowFocusChanged` method, but this doesn't work, since when I start a webservice download, I bring up a progress dialog and close it upon completion.  This causes a recursive effect (the dialog closes and gives focus back to the list activity).

Is there any way I can get when the activity is first shown?  Similar to `viewWillAppear` for iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just override `onResume()` in the Activity. Just make sure to do whatever internet communication you do in a separate thread.

Comment: I thought there was something like that, I somehow missed it when looking over the activity documentation.  That's not gonna have the same problem?

Comment: It shouldn't, I don't believe. Give it a try and see what happens (I don't work with dialogs much)

Comment: No, onResume is called everytime your app is brought back to the front.  Check out this Activity Lifecycle here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Also, make sure you still call super.onResume() in your overridden method or else you'll get an error!